# Where is my hat in the Android app?

Tags: feature-request, android-app, winter-bash, winter-bash-2016

This year for the first time I noticed Winterbash, I really like it, the hats are awesome!

But there is one thing that would make it even better, adding the hats also to the StackExchange App! Right now, I feel that it is a bit ironic that you can get a hat (cutting the cord) for using the app but you can't see it in that same app..

So could we also get hats in the app next year?

(I'm on Android btw. Based on [the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288531/hat-inconsistencies-in-ios-app) found by Glorfindel, iOS does have hats.)

Answer (score 16):

<sub>This post was written at the time it wasn't clear which app (iOS/Android) the OP was talking about.</sub>

In theory, the iOS app supports hats; [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288531/hat-inconsistencies-in-ios-app) on Meta Stack Exchange suggests that the implementation is a little buggy. I haven't seen any hats in the app myself either.

[image]

Comment: I'm on Android so that explains why I even don't see the buggy hats. Off topic, you should get a hat for that awesome paint hat!

Comment: Sorry for assuming you meant the iOS app, but it wasn't clear from your question. And thanks for the compliment. It's the season of Freehand Hats!

Comment: Better citation for the iOS one: [No hats on mobile](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246359/no-hats-on-mobile/270790#270790).

Comment: Hey look I'm in a meta post!

Comment: @JAL [join the club](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/340148/4751173).