# Is there any way to know which user currently has the most hats?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2016

Is there any way to know which user currently has the most hats? I have looked at some profiles; the maximum I found up to now is 18 hats achieved.

The list is:

1. [Glorfindel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4751173/glorfindel?tab=topactivity)
2. [Unheilig](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2227834/unheilig?tab=topactivity)

But it is not doable to go to all user's profile and check their hats.

**My Question:** Is there any way to get a list of users with the most hats?

Comment: "Not doable" Speak for yourself!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There's a leaderboard [here](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/leaderboard). You can click on the icons on the left to show the [network leaderboard](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/network) and the [per-site leaderboards](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/stackoverflow.com).

I'm far from being the #1, though. That would currently be [Alexander O'Mara](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3155639/alexander-omara?tab=topactivity).

Comment: Far too quick for me!

Comment: @Glorfindel thanks this is what I looking for.

Comment: I'm starting to see why OP thought you were #1... Good answer.